# How to use google talk gadget in website

Tags: javascript, chat, google-talk

I want to embed gtalk chat gadget so that users would be able to chat within my website.
FAQ here - http://support.google.com/talk/answer/2722317?hl=en says that Google discontinued Google Talk Gadget.
But as I can see from http://google.com/ig, the chat gadget works fine in iGoogle.
Is it possible somehow to extract the javascript/html code from there and use it in your own website? Or any other alternative ideas?

I want something like http://karoolark.com/#gtalk